# which wget returns error: /usr/bin/env: «node»: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, arch-linux, environment-variables, which

I uninstalled nodejs the other day and now for some reason when I access it I get the error that node is not found. The argument of the which command can be anything.

```
> which wget                                                                                                                                                                        
/usr/bin/env: «node»: No such file or directory
```

However, if I install the node again, everything is fine:

```
> sudo pacman -S nodejs
...

> which wget                                                                                                                                                              
/usr/bin/wget
```

Comment: not sure why `which` is tied to `nodejs` - perhaps, while node is installed, find which which is `which` by running `which which` and remove it

Comment: My first though was also that nodejs replaces `which` and that the version it installs is not removed when you uninstall nodejs. (I think that basically what @JaromandaX is going for).

Comment: to be clear, nodejs does not replace which